# ROT13 encode/decode string but don't change characters within brackets []

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, encoding, nsstring

I have a simple [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) method that encodes or decodes a string.

```
+ (NSString *)ROT13encodeString:(NSString *)aString {

    if (!aString) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Find text between brackets
    NSCharacterSet *delimiters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"[]"];
    NSArray *splitString = [aString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:delimiters];
    // ???

    NSString *newString;
    unsigned length;
    unichar *buf;
    unsigned i;

    length = [aString length];
    buf = malloc( (length + 1) * sizeof(unichar) );
    [aString getCharacters:buf];
    buf[length] = (unichar)0; // not really needed....
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (buf[i] >= (unichar)'a' && buf[i] <= (unichar) 'z') {
            buf[i] += 13;
            if (buf[i] > 'z') buf[i] -= 26;
        } else if (buf[i] >= (unichar)'A' && buf[i] <= (unichar) 'Z') {
            buf[i] += 13;
            if (buf[i] > 'Z') buf[i] -= 26;
        }
    }
    newString = [NSString stringWithCharacters:buf length:length];
    free(buf);
    return newString;

}
```

However, within the text to encode, there are "safe" words that are placed within brackets []. The words, including the brackets should never be encoded, they always need to be in their non-encoded state.

I figured I could pull out all occururances of the bracketed text, but not sure how it would help:

```
NSCharacterSet *delimiters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"[]"];
NSArray *splitString = [aString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:delimiters];
```

**How could I modify my current method to include this?**

Comment: I wouldn't bother splitting the string.  I would set a flag while looping through the characters when you find  a `[` and unset it when you find `]` don't do the rot-13ing on each character while the flag is set.  Might have to be slightly more complicated depending on if/how you want to handle nested brackets.

Comment: Agreed with dan. Using an `NSScanner` might make your life easier overall, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't code in objective-c, but I think this should be close:

```
+ (NSString *)ROT13encodeString:(NSString *)aString {

    if (!aString) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Find text between brackets
    NSCharacterSet *delimiters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"[]"];
    NSArray *splitString = [aString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:delimiters];
    // ???

    NSString *newString;
    unsigned length;
    unichar *buf;
    unsigned i;
    unsigned level;

    length = [aString length];
    buf = malloc( (length + 1) * sizeof(unichar) );
    [aString getCharacters:buf];
    buf[length] = (unichar)0; // not really needed....
    level = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (buf[i] == (unichar)'[') {
          level++;
        } else if (buf[i] == (unichar)']') {
          level--;
        } else if (level==0 && buf[i] >= (unichar)'a' && buf[i] <= (unichar) 'z') {
            buf[i] += 13;
            if (buf[i] > 'z') buf[i] -= 26;
        } else if (level==0 && buf[i] >= (unichar)'A' && buf[i] <= (unichar) 'Z') {
            buf[i] += 13;
            if (buf[i] > 'Z') buf[i] -= 26;
        }
    }
    newString = [NSString stringWithCharacters:buf length:length];
    free(buf);
    return newString;

}
```

Comment: You might want to check for unbalanced brackets (or closing without opening).. `level` would be `< 0`